# How to know my file download Url is invalid using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file

I have an anchor tag in my AngularJS component that links to a file, but I want to be able to detect if the file at that location exists to give an alert message. How can this be done?

```html
<a ng-href="{{row.General_FileJson.DiskPath}}" download="{{row.General_FileJson.Name}}">file download</a>
```

Comment: Assuming you're not blocked by CORS, you could send an AJAX HEAD request and examine the response.

Comment: When I try to download an invalid source file it tries to download a file and says download fails.

Answer (score 0):

You could use JavaScript (or rather TypeScript) to make an asynchronous call to the url and check the status code:

```js
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();  
request.open('HEAD', 'http://www.mozilla.org', true);
request.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (request.readyState === 4){
        if (request.status === 404) {  
            alert("This file does not exist!");
        }  
    }
};
request.send();
```

The example above is just vanilla JavaScript, but you can also use a library or even a dedicated Angular service of course.

Comment: yeah this is helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
    $scope.getFile = function (path, file) {
        $http.get(path).success(function (result) {
            console.log(result);
            var a = document.createElement("a");
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.style = "display: none";
            a.href = path;
            a.download = file;
            a.click();
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        }).error(function (result, status) {
            $scope.HasError = true;
            $scope.ErrorMsg = "Unable to download this file! ";
            alertError($scope.ErrorMsg);

        });
    }
```

```html
<a href="" ng-click="getFile(Url, FileName)">file download</a>
```